# Trafficserver crashes after upgrade to Ubuntu Bionic Segmentation fault (Address not mapped to object [(nil)])

Tags: ubuntu

I upgraded Apache Trafficserver from Ubuntu Artful to Bionic, and after that I could't get trafficserver to start, but I got this kind of error message:

```
[Apr  2 10:47:23.389] traffic_crashlog {0x2b5cd50b9880} ERROR: wrote crash log to /var/log/trafficserver/crash-2018-04-02-104721.log
traffic_server: Segmentation fault (Address not mapped to object [(nil)])
traffic_server - STACK TRACE: 
/usr/bin/traffic_server(_Z19crash_logger_invokeiP9siginfo_tPv+0xa0)[0x55ccecdb9e80]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11670)[0x2b7bc04c3670]
[Apr  2 11:07:34.477] traffic_crashlog {0x2b98affdf880} NOTE: crashlog started, target=3434, debug=false syslog=true, uid=0 euid=0
[Apr  2 11:07:35.004] traffic_crashlog {0x2b98affdf880} NOTE: logging to 0x5570b439f1a0
[Apr  2 11:07:36.383] traffic_crashlog {0x2b98affdf880} ERROR: wrote crash log to /var/log/trafficserver/crash-2018-04-02-110734.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Google was unhelpful, but I managed to debug it by launching trafficserver by hand:

```
root@bob:/var/log/trafficserver# traffic_manager 
[E. Mgmt] log ==> [TrafficManager] using root directory '/usr'
[Jun 21 08:15:28.889] Manager {0x7f4b7c9ab740} ERROR: unable to access() local state directory '/var/run/trafficserver': 2, No such file or directory
[Jun 21 08:15:28.889] Manager {0x7f4b7c9ab740} ERROR: unable to access() local state directory '/var/run/trafficserver': 2, No such file or directory
[Jun 21 08:15:28.889] Manager {0x7f4b7c9ab740} ERROR: please set 'proxy.config.local_state_dir'
[Jun 21 08:15:28.889] Manager {0x7f4b7c9ab740} ERROR: please set 'proxy.config.local_state_dir'
```

After this I created the missing directory and got it to work

```
mkdir /var/run/trafficserver
chown -R trafficserver:trafficserver /var/run/trafficserver
```